# QT and web development bridge

Tags: qt

Is there a project that allows me to convert a Qt project (one MainWindow, a simple GUI) to somehting that can run on a browser? I'd think there's nothing technical that prevents this from happening.

I programmed an annotation tool in Qt but on second thought it would have been much better if it run on a browser, though I don't know zip about Javascript.

It may not work magically, but are there any helpers at least towards this goal?

Answer (score 8):

It is not exactly the same but the [Wt C++ Toolkit](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) offers you an API which I find quite similar to the Qt one. Perhaps converting your project to Wt might be quite easy!

Wt makes your application a specialized HTTP server (or perhaps a FastCgi application).

Comment: +1 since ideal solution if the desired QT app has more of C++ than QML.

But also advisable to the check the License and Pricing (http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/download)

If used as GNU General Public License (GPL), you may build a web application with Wt and deploy it, but you are obliged to make the source code available to anyone who you give the application to install the application on its own server. This also applies to redistribution of the Wt library, in original or modified form.

The Commercial License has no such limitations.

Comment: wt also has another advantage, it's tailored for web from the start. analytics works better, you don't need javascript, css, google closure compiler, bootstrap and lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 8):

[QtWui](http://qtwui.sourceforge.net/) is a module for Qt that enables you to write web applications just like you where writing a standard desktop GUI application with QtGui. It comes with a simple web server that runs the application. In the future it will also be possible to use an external web server that supports FastCGI.

General principle

The idea behind QtWui is that each connected user opens a new session on the server and this session is like a standard application process on a desktop computer. Each session has a lifetime that can be configured. If no user action occurs before the end of the session lifetime, it is destroyed.

Internal machinery

[image: QtWui Internal machinery]

Answer (score 1):

You can check out GCF from VCreateLogic ([GCF Web Link](http://www.vcreatelogic.com/products/gcf)). It is a component framework built on top of Qt and has helper components to make your Qt application available through a web browser. They have a open source version and you can surely download and play with it to see if this is what you are looking for.

PS: I have no relationship with VCreateLogic and had seen a demo of GCF where they showcased what you are looking for.